# CMake Project use local g++ version

Tags: macos, g++, cmake

I'm using MacOS X Lion with XCode 4.2.1. and I need gcc 2.4.6. to compile a CMake project. Therefor I build gcc 2.4.6. on my own in a local directory `$HOME/mygcc/bin`. Is there a way to influece the path to the compiler CMake uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use the GUI to set these variables:

```
CMAKE_C_COMPILER=$HOME/mygcc/bingcc
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$HOME/mygcc/bing++
```

Or you can run `cmake` from the commandline:

```
cmake ../path/to/source -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$HOME/mygcc/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$HOME/mygcc/bin/g++
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your local gcc bin directory into your `$PATH` before running `cmake`:

```
$ export PATH=$HOME/mygcc/bin:$PATH
$ cmake
```